# Why doesn't x:Static work in my WPF example?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

[This is .Net 3.5.]  I have seen a lot of examples that say, do it this way, so I must just be missing something:

I have a project with a Resources.resx file.  In the Resources file are Strings that are Public.  One of them is "Cancel", shown in this snippet from Resources.Designer.cs:

```
namespace WFT.PumpSvc.Bench.Properties {
    public class Resources {
        public static string Cancel {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Cancel", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
...
```

Next, I have some xaml that has

```
xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:WFT.PumpSvc.Bench.Properties"
```

and

```
<wft:TouchButton Name="closeButton">"{x:Static strings:Resources.Cancel}"</wft:TouchButton>
```

(TouchButton inherits from Button.)

Instead of "Cancel" showing on my button, I see {x:Static strings:Resources.Cancel}.  Is it obvious what I have missed that isn't finding the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write a markup extension directly in an element (at least not in this form), it must be in an attribute:

```
<wft:TouchButton Name="closeButton" Content="{x:Static strings:Resources.Cancel}"></wft:TouchButton>
```

You can also write it like this:

```
<wft:TouchButton Name="closeButton">
    <x:Static Member="strings:Resources.Cancel" />
</wft:TouchButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

You made it a string, it won't be parsed like this, use element-syntax:

```
<wft:TouchButton Name="closeButton">
     <x:Static Member="strings:Resources.Cancel"/>
</wft:TouchButton>
```